# Width of embedded HighChart within jQuery dialog only 100% after resizing window screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I can make my HighChart chart appear in a fixed positioned jQuery dialog, which width is set as a percentage minus certain pixels.

But my problem is, that once I open the dialog, the width of the chart is not the same as the width of my dialog. Only after I resize my browser window the chart gets the same width as the jQuery dialog window.

Here a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63oa26ah/) to show what I mean. 
How can I solve this?

And see below for 'show code snippet' if jsfiddle is down, but unfortunately  'run code snippet' doesn't seen to work (same code as jsfiddle though).

```js
$('.selector').dialog({
  dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: false,
  clickOut: true
});

$("#opener").click(function() {
  $(".selector").dialog("open");
});


$(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
      renderTo: 'stock-chart',
      margin: 0,
      defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline'
    },
    xAxis: {
      minPadding: 0,
      maxPadding: 0
    },
    series: [{
      data: [33, 4, 15, 6, 7, 8, 73, 2, 33, 4, 25],

      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.fixed-dialog {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 50px !important;
  left: 50px !important;
  width: calc(90% - 50px) !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasonday/jQuery-UI-Dialog-extended/master/jquery.dialogOptions.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p/>
  <div class="selector" title="Dialog Title">
    <div id="stock-chart" style="calc(90% - 50px) !important; "></div>

  </div>


  <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</body>
```

Comment: well as for the code snippet, the $().dialog doesn't seem to be pulled in for the definition. Dunno why that is. For your inline-css, you forgot to specify the style key, you just have calc(90%-50px) !important; you probably meant to do width: calc(90%-50px) !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known problem, when rendering chart in a hidden container. Browser can't calculate width, so chart is using default width/height values for the chart.

Solution is simple: update chart's width/height when opening dialog.

```
$('.selector').dialog({
  dialogClass: 'fixed-dialog',
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: false,
  clickOut: true,
  open: function(){
    var chart = $("#stock-chart").highcharts();
    if(chart) {
      chart.reflow();
    }
  }
});
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/63oa26ah/6/